# .net service with flexible filename

Tags: .net, windows, service, .net-assembly, filenotfoundexception

I am building a Windows service using the .NET plateform. The service is intended to run on multiple clients, each instance for each client. Each service instance will work on separate database. All of the service instances will be on a single server.

Recently, the customer (hosting the server on which the service is running) asked that when he views the service in Windows Task Manager, he could not tell which service executable is for which customer. So, he unregistered the services, made multiple copies of the service exe and then renamed them like appending the customer name in the file name. He then registered the service. But when he tried to run the service he started to get

> Service cannot be started. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'AService, Version=2013.0.0.1004, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4a70863d203e0028' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I spent a couple of days to find a solution but couldn't. Can somebody please help me with this? Is renaming assemblies like this even allowed by .NET?

Comment: Renaming an EXE should work fine. How did your customer register the new services?

Answer (score 0):

Try
Rename assembles in runtime on calling name not found,
 works with all references !

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/837908/en-us

Method 3

Comment: Thanks for the reply. All of these methods are talking about the refrenced assmeblies not the executing assembly. In my case the executing assemly's filename is different than the assembly name. And unfortunately this name was changed after the build.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is altogether different then what I asked. My bad. The service loads assemblies dynamically depending on the customer. The dynamic loading logic was taken from [Loading Assemblies from Anywhere into a New AppDomain](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/453778/Loading-Assemblies-from-Anywhere-into-a-New-AppDom). Apparently, the FileNotFoundException was occurring because of this. The dynamic load works when the service exe file is not renamed.